# Hiding or minimizing ribbon in powerpoint

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in, ribbon

I am developing a Powerpoint addin (vsto), and I would like to hide or minimize the ribbon.
In Word there is method for it -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.window.toggleribbon%28v=office.14%29.aspx
I am looking for some equivalent for it in Powerpoint, any ideas?